# Was there any politization of "hard" science (math, physics, chemistry, biology) in the Asian communist countries?

Tags: science, communism, asia

Where proven science results contradict political views, the most obvious solution is to try to discredit those results, by creating your own versions. It has been done multiple times in history, for example, the *[Deutsche_Physik](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deutsche_Physik) and [Mathematik](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deutsche_Mathematik)* were created to fight with "Jewish" science (mainly Einstein's theory of relativity) while *[Lysenkoism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lysenkoism)* was a Marxist answer to imperialistic Darwin's theory of natural selection. In recent years we had (hopefully short living) movement calling  that "[Science must fall!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C9SiRNibD14)" in South Africa (because science has been created by white people).  [The list is long...](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Politicization_of_science)

Were there similar movements in the Asian communist countries (Mao's China, Pol Pot's Cambodia, North Korea) created to contradict established (and confirmed at that moment) science?

To clarify: I am not looking for obvious propaganda (as in "we can raise 100 x more grain on the same area and produce 1000 x more steel than Capitalists using the same amount of resources because of magic and smoking cigarettes is good for you and smoking Marihuana is bad, because the tobacco industry/forestry is important for economy), obvious manipulations of history or false correlation fallacy (i.e. if rise of birds of populations happens at the same time as rice of oil price, then killing birds could reduce the cost of oil)

I'm looking for examples similar to mentioned above from Nazi Germany/Stalinist Soviet Union: when state was supporting math, physics, chemistry or biology for the ideological reasons contradicting the proofs created by Western science.

In an example, I'm looking for something like "It is untrue that Americans landed on the Moon **because our scientists have proven** that it is impossible" or "Quantum theory is incorrect **because our scientists have proven** that atoms are the smallest possible particle".

EDIt: this wiki page shows [suppressed research in the Soviet Union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suppressed_research_in_the_Soviet_Union), which includes parts of physics, cybernetics or statistics. I'm looking for something similar in regards to other communists Asian countries

EDIT2: I am interested only in the sciences described in the topic, which EXCLUDES various natural/alternative/traditional medicine, psychology, sociology, religion, philosophy etc.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95474/discussion-on-question-by-yasskier-was-there-any-politization-of-hard-science).

Answer (score 2):

If you look into the details of the page on [suppressed research in the Soviet Union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suppressed_research_in_the_Soviet_Union) that you linked to you'll notice that very little hard science got politicized in practice. At worst there were a few rough starts and things fell into place.

On biology, which to me stood out as one of the two hard science examples that endured serious suppression efforts:

> Later Soviet biologists heavily criticised Lysenko's theories and pseudo-scientific methods.

On cybernetics:

> After an initial period of doubts, Soviet cybernetics took root

On physics:

> this process did not go as far as defining an "ideologically correct" version of physics [...] because this was recognized as potentially too harmful

On statistics, which also stood out to me as having endured serious suppression efforts:

> the policy of not publishing, or simply not collecting, data that was deemed unsuitable for various reasons was much more common than simple falsification

The above being to say, there's no shortage of rewriting history or suppressing inconvenient data, but given how even the USSR couldn't pull off passing anything like the [Indiana Pi bill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indiana_Pi_Bill) with a straight face, I sincerely doubt that Asian Communist states tried it let alone succeeded.

Comment: The backlash against Lysenko was as political as his rise to power... When he fell in disgrace after his political sponsors fell, his former followers immediately flipflopped and denounced him to save their own skin and positions.